# How to make note bigger (musicography)?

Tags: fonts, music

How do I adjust the size of the dotted quaver note (I use the musicography package, but it could be any other package that is easy to use.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musicography}
    
\begin{document}
Tempo~in~bpm=\musQuarterDotted
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use `\usepackage[bigger]{musicography}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musicography,graphicx}
    
\begin{document}
Tempo~in~bpm=\musQuarterDotted

Tempo~in~bpm=\scalebox{1.5}{\musQuarterDotted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  Of course, line spacings could be affected, unless you (for example) `\smash` it.

Comment: Thank you. It works just fine!