# Change font size for Dynamic Mark Symbol in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to increase the font size for Dynamic Mark Symbol in Musixtex, which is different from text font size, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{longtable}%Para tablas largas
%\newsavebox{\tablaPuntilloSimple}

\begin{document}

%Se requiere habilitar las fuentes de TEX en esta sección
\font\ctinytype=cmr7
\font\ctinytypebf=cmbx7
\font\ctinytypeit=cmti7
\font\csmalltype=cmr8
\font\csmalltypebf=cmbx8
\font\csmalltypeit=cmti8
\font\cSmalltype=cmr9
\font\cSmalltypebf=cmbx9
\font\cSmalltypeit=cmti9
\font\cnormtype=cmr10
\font\cnormtypebf=cmbx10
\font\cnormtypeit=cmti10
\font\cnormtypebi=cmbxti10
\font\cnormtypesc=cmcsc10
\font\cmedtype=cmr12
\font\cmedtypebf=cmbx12
\font\cmedtypeit=cmti12
\font\cmedtypebi=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cmedtypesc=cmcsc10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cbigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep1
\font\cBigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep2
\font\cBIgtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep3
\font\cBIGtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep4
\font\cppfftwelve=cmbxti10 at 8pt
\font\cppffsixteen=cmbxti10
\font\cppfftwenty=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cppfftwentyfour=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep2
\font\cppfftwentynine=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep3
\font\cbigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep1
\font\cBigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep2
\font\cBIgtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep3
\font\cBIGfont=cmbx12 scaled \magstep4
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\begin{longtable}[H]{lll}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
%  \begin{tabular}{lll}
%  \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.7} Tama\~{n}o y estilo  &  Especificaci\'on de fuente & Ejemplo \\
    \hline
    \verb|\tinytype|    & \verb|\sevenrm| & {\ctinytype    tiny Roman}  \\
    \verb|\tinytype\bf| & \verb|\sevenbf| & {\ctinytypebf tiny bold}   \\
    \verb|\tinytype\it| & \verb|\sevenit| & {\ctinytypeit tiny italic} \\
    \verb|\smalltype|    & \verb|\eightrm| & {\csmalltype    small Roman}  \\
    \verb|\smalltype\bf| & \verb|\eightbf| & {\csmalltypebf small bold}   \\
    \verb|\smalltype\it| & \verb|\eightit| & {\csmalltypeit small italic} \\
    \verb|\Smalltype|    & \verb|\ninerm| & {\cSmalltype    Small Roman}  \\
    \verb|\Smalltype\bf| & \verb|\ninebf| & {\cSmalltypebf Small bold}   \\
    \verb|\Smalltype\it| & \verb|\nineit| & {\cSmalltypeit Small italic} \\
    \verb|\normtype|     & \verb|\tenrm| & {\cnormtype     normal Roman} \\
    \verb|\normtype\bf|  & \verb|\tenbf| & {\cnormtypebf  normal bold}  \\
    \verb|\normtype\it|  & \verb|\tenit| & {\cnormtypeit  normal italic}\\
    \verb|\normtype\bi|  & \verb|\tenbi| & {\cnormtypebi  normal bold italic}\\
    \verb|\normtype\sc|  & \verb|\tensc| & {\cnormtypesc  normal small capitals}\\
    \verb|\medtype|      & \verb|\twelverm| & {\cmedtype      medium Roman} \\
    \verb|\medtype\bf|   & \verb|\twelvebf| & {\cmedtypebf   medium bold}  \\
    \verb|\medtype\it|   & \verb|\twelveit| & {\cmedtypeit   medium italic}\\
    \verb|\medtype\bi|  & \verb|\twelvebi| & {\cmedtypebi  medium bold italic}\\
    \verb|\medtype\sc|  & \verb|\twelvesc| & {\cmedtypesc  medium small capitals}\\
    \verb|\bigtype|      & \verb|\frtbf| & {\cbigtype      big bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\Bigtype|      & \verb|\svtbf| & {\cBigtype      Big bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\BIgtype|      & \verb|\twtybf| & {\cBIgtype      BIg bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\BIGtype|      & \verb|\twfvbf| & {\cBIGtype      BIG bold}     \\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwelve| & {\cppfftwelve  pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppffsixteen| & {\cppffsixteen  pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwenty| & {\cppfftwenty   pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwentyfour| & {\cppfftwentyfour   pp ff diminuendo}\\[.4ex]
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwentynine| & {\cppfftwentynine   pp ff diminuendo}\\[.4ex]
    \hline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{center}}
\caption{Varias fuentes predefinidas}
\label{tab:fuentesPredefinidas}
\end{longtable}

% Focus here:
Changing font size for text letter:
{\cBIGtype f}

Changing font size for Musixtex Dynamic Mark symbol:
{\cBIGtype \f}

Trying changing the font:
\font\xppff=xppff10  
\xppff f



\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current output]

The expected size for Dynamic Mark Symbol is as follow (more bigger):

[image: expected output]

Comment: Solved using: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651058/how-to-make-note-bigger-musicography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{longtable}%Para tablas largas
%\newsavebox{\tablaPuntilloSimple}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%Se requiere habilitar las fuentes de TEX en esta sección
\font\ctinytype=cmr7
\font\ctinytypebf=cmbx7
\font\ctinytypeit=cmti7
\font\csmalltype=cmr8
\font\csmalltypebf=cmbx8
\font\csmalltypeit=cmti8
\font\cSmalltype=cmr9
\font\cSmalltypebf=cmbx9
\font\cSmalltypeit=cmti9
\font\cnormtype=cmr10
\font\cnormtypebf=cmbx10
\font\cnormtypeit=cmti10
\font\cnormtypebi=cmbxti10
\font\cnormtypesc=cmcsc10
\font\cmedtype=cmr12
\font\cmedtypebf=cmbx12
\font\cmedtypeit=cmti12
\font\cmedtypebi=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cmedtypesc=cmcsc10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cbigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep1
\font\cBigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep2
\font\cBIgtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep3
\font\cBIGtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep4
\font\cppfftwelve=cmbxti10 at 8pt
\font\cppffsixteen=cmbxti10
\font\cppfftwenty=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep1
\font\cppfftwentyfour=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep2
\font\cppfftwentynine=cmbxti10 scaled \magstep3
\font\cbigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep1
\font\cBigtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep2
\font\cBIgtype=cmbx12 scaled \magstep3
\font\cBIGfont=cmbx12 scaled \magstep4
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\begin{longtable}[H]{lll}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
%  \begin{tabular}{lll}
%  \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.7} Tama\~{n}o y estilo  &  Especificaci\'on de fuente & Ejemplo \\
    \hline
    \verb|\tinytype|    & \verb|\sevenrm| & {\ctinytype    tiny Roman}  \\
    \verb|\tinytype\bf| & \verb|\sevenbf| & {\ctinytypebf tiny bold}   \\
    \verb|\tinytype\it| & \verb|\sevenit| & {\ctinytypeit tiny italic} \\
    \verb|\smalltype|    & \verb|\eightrm| & {\csmalltype    small Roman}  \\
    \verb|\smalltype\bf| & \verb|\eightbf| & {\csmalltypebf small bold}   \\
    \verb|\smalltype\it| & \verb|\eightit| & {\csmalltypeit small italic} \\
    \verb|\Smalltype|    & \verb|\ninerm| & {\cSmalltype    Small Roman}  \\
    \verb|\Smalltype\bf| & \verb|\ninebf| & {\cSmalltypebf Small bold}   \\
    \verb|\Smalltype\it| & \verb|\nineit| & {\cSmalltypeit Small italic} \\
    \verb|\normtype|     & \verb|\tenrm| & {\cnormtype     normal Roman} \\
    \verb|\normtype\bf|  & \verb|\tenbf| & {\cnormtypebf  normal bold}  \\
    \verb|\normtype\it|  & \verb|\tenit| & {\cnormtypeit  normal italic}\\
    \verb|\normtype\bi|  & \verb|\tenbi| & {\cnormtypebi  normal bold italic}\\
    \verb|\normtype\sc|  & \verb|\tensc| & {\cnormtypesc  normal small capitals}\\
    \verb|\medtype|      & \verb|\twelverm| & {\cmedtype      medium Roman} \\
    \verb|\medtype\bf|   & \verb|\twelvebf| & {\cmedtypebf   medium bold}  \\
    \verb|\medtype\it|   & \verb|\twelveit| & {\cmedtypeit   medium italic}\\
    \verb|\medtype\bi|  & \verb|\twelvebi| & {\cmedtypebi  medium bold italic}\\
    \verb|\medtype\sc|  & \verb|\twelvesc| & {\cmedtypesc  medium small capitals}\\
    \verb|\bigtype|      & \verb|\frtbf| & {\cbigtype      big bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\Bigtype|      & \verb|\svtbf| & {\cBigtype      Big bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\BIgtype|      & \verb|\twtybf| & {\cBIgtype      BIg bold}     \\[.4ex]
    \verb|\BIGtype|      & \verb|\twfvbf| & {\cBIGtype      BIG bold}     \\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwelve| & {\cppfftwelve  pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppffsixteen| & {\cppffsixteen  pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwenty| & {\cppfftwenty   pp ff diminuendo}\\
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwentyfour| & {\cppfftwentyfour   pp ff diminuendo}\\[.4ex]
    ~                   & \verb|\ppfftwentynine| & {\cppfftwentynine   pp ff diminuendo}\\[.4ex]
    \hline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{center}}
\caption{Varias fuentes predefinidas}
\label{tab:fuentesPredefinidas}
\end{longtable}

% Focus here:
Changing font size for text letter:
{\cBIGtype f}

Changing font size for Musixtex Dynamic Mark symbol:
{\cBIGtype \f}
\scalebox{2.5}{\f}

Trying changing the font:
\font\xppff=xppff10  
\xppff f


\end{document}
```